# Pull credit card info from a paypal transaction ID

Tags: paypal, transactions

My client is currently using existing transaction IDs in order to bill his customers monthly. They are looking to move away from this approach and switch to recurring payments. For this purpose I need to have the credit card info of each customer. So the question is whether it is possible to somehow get the credit card info from the paypal's transaction ID in order to initiate a recurring payment. I know that Authorize.net stores CC info within 3 months after the last transaction. Is this the case with PayPal? If not, maybe somebody has already found a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you cannot get credit card information out of PayPal's systems. You'll need to create a migration flow in the site for users to create a recurring payment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you mean have the users manually re-enter their payment info in their profiles?